# In django, how do I use a select2 widget for a manytomanyfield?

Tags: django

I want to use a select2 widget for a manytomanyfield in django.  There are several django/select2 modules, but the documentation is confusing, and I can't find a simple example of what I want.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: django-select2-forms does it extremely simple.

Answer (score 12):

Good place to start is [django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django_select2.html), they have a good work [example](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/tree/master/tests/testapp) also.

Here I just figure out the main idea in the context of their example

model

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    featured_artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, blank=True, related_name='featured_album_set')
    primary_genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, blank=True, null=True, related_name='primary_album_set')
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The fields what are will be mapped to the select2 presented here with ManyToMany relationship type.

form

```
class AlbumSelect2WidgetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Album
        fields = (
            'artist',
            'primary_genre',
        )
        widgets = {
            'artist': Select2Widget,
            'primary_genre': Select2Widget,

        }
```

It is very easy to customize Select2Widget, if it will be need.

And the final - html part

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  {{ form.media.css }}
  <style type="text/css">
    select {
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
<script src="{% static '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onerror = function (msg) {
    $("body").attr("JSError", msg);
  }
</script>
{{ form.media.js }}
</body>
```

Comment: where do have to edit this , template ,

Comment: this answer needs further explanation: you state "The fields what are will be mapped to the select2 presented here with ManyToMany relationship type" but the provided code only shows the ForeignKey fields being mapped to widgets, not the M2M fields. It's not at all clear why, nor how it works (if it does work).

Answer (score 9):

In Django >= 2.0,

> The new ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields attribute and
>   ModelAdmin.get_autocomplete_fields() method allow using an Select2
>   search widget for ForeignKey and ManyToManyField.

Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#minor-features